# Is CSRF a threat if not using cookies?

Tags: ajax, security, flask, xmlhttprequest, csrf

My `Flask` app is `AJAX`-heavy, but does not use any cookies. Is `CSRF` still a threat or is it safe to deploy the app as of now?

I have already looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732087/is-csrf-possible-without-cookies) but my situation is slightly different, since I do not have to worry about user's credentials.

I tried an `AJAX` call from `Chrome DevTools` (using `$.ajax()`) to my server which was running on `localhost` (`Flask` development server) and I got an error saying

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/_ajax. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome://newtab' is therefore not allowed access.

Does this mean I am safe, or is it possible that a hacker could circumvent this and still make `AJAX` calls to my server?

Comment: You don't need csrf protection if there's nothing on your site to protect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF isn't just protection against CORS AJAX. I could make a form on my site, and set the action to http://yoursite.com/account/delete. If a user submits my form, without CSRF on your site, the action would succeed. Or if you have things change on GET requests (shouldn't do that anyway), I could add this to my site:

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/account/delete" />
```

and the action would happen when my page loads.

Check out Flask-WTF or this snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/3/

**EDIT**

From your comment:

Change the action of that page to a POST, and have it be accessed through a form instead of a link. If your link was:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('my_page') }}">Click Here</>
```

Your form could be (using Flask-WTF, which you would need):

```
<form action="{{ url_for('my_page') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here" />
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "things change on GET requests"? Also, all but one of my `AJAX` calls retrieve non-sensitive data, and the other sends a download to the user, so is there still a risk?

Comment: If you're changing user data when the load a page instead of when they submit a form.

Comment: Would an example of this be going to a certain page which deletes your user account? Also, I have a page that, when accessed, makes some changes to a database, and then returns some data (I remove invalid values from the database and then return data). Would this count as an example of what not to do?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help.